# "Special" or "specials"

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, grammatical-number

I would like to know if in the following sentence, *special* should be plural or not.

> The red apples are not special.

I do not feel that this is correct.

Comment: Hello and welcome. This question is too basic for this site. You might be interested in our proposed sister site for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). You can support it by committing. Thank you.

Comment: Would it similarly bother you if someone said that the special apples were not red?  Would you want them to be reds instead?

Comment: Hello @RegDwighт I understand and thank you for provide me this information...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adjectives in English are not inflected for number. *Special* describing a single object remains *special* when applied to more than one.

> The red apples are not special.
>   The special apples are not red.
>   The English apples are tasty.

None of the adjectives, *red, special, English* or *tasty,* differ from a "singular" form.

Comment: Well, apart from the four demonstrative determiners (*this, these, that, those*), which some folks (rather dubiously) call adjectives.

Answer (score 7):

In English, plural adjectives are not written differently:

> - One apple is special.
> - Two apples are special.

If you put an "s" at the end of special, then you're treating it like a noun:

> - I watched a special last night on holiday traditions.
> - I watched two specials last night, one after the other.